# Can't connect to upgraded TFS 2008 Project Collection in TFS 2012

Tags: tfs

I have successfully installed TFS 2012 and migrated my TFS 2008 databases into TFS 2012.  From within Visual Studio I am able to connect to the new TFS server through my source control plugin and can see all of the projects that were imported from TFS 2008.  The problem is that when I click 'Connect' I am getting an exception that an HTTP 500 error has occurred. On the server I am getting a warning in the Event Viewer because of this URL:

http://[servername]:8080/tfs/tfs2008projectcollection/services/v3.0/locationservice.asmx/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/LocationService.asmx

If I manually go to the above URL minus '/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/LocationService.asmx' the page loads fine.  Additionally if I remove '/tfs2008projectcollection/services/v3.0/locationservice.asmx' and navigate to http://[servername]:8080/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/LocationService.asmx the page loads fine.

Thing is this only happens with the project collection that I imported from 2008. I created a new project collection directly in TFS 2012 and I can connect to that project just fine within VS 2012.  Has anyone ran into this issue and, if so, what is the best way to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

It is  unclear what caused / is causing this problem but after a TFS server reboot the issue is no longer manifesting itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm am also having this issue.  I have Update 4 and this is a fresh machine.  I see the issue [here](http://www.datazx.cn/Fv7p5a/87/24as651w/2q7xs6/6jdfr6fs-99ji-fg6f-bi69-mjgfts6m9g8r23rsdfd.html), have tried the fix and no luck.  I've also tried a reboot with no luck.  I see the issue [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0d20917a-73ad-4c97-a524-21952f522e83/tfs-app-server-event-3000-tfs-services-tf53010-tf30065-invalid-url-locationserviceasmx?forum=tfsgeneral) and it appears that Microsoft's only suggestion is to 2013.  Unfortunately they do not supply a migration path directly between 2008 and 2013, so I have to cross my fingers and hope that upgrading the machine after importing from 2008 even with the error will solve the issue.

Can anyone confirm the issue is actually resolved in 2013?